# How do i parse this time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, datetime

I have this string

```
   day = "2012-03-07T16-02-54"
```

and i need to insert in a mysql datetime and preserve the time as well

if i do

```
   self.original_date = date
```

I lose the time

```
 original_date: "2012-03-07 00:00:00"
```

Comment: What have you tried except for naive assignment? For example, haven't you at least considered simple string replacement technique to transform the time into a form understood by the assignment method?

Comment: I tried strptime and Date.parse...i am using ruby 1.9.2 ...is that really a reason for the downvote

Comment: You should add those attempts to the quesiton. Why didn't they work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because of the time format, try something like this:

```
self.original_date = DateTime.strptime(day, "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")
```

where `day = "2012-03-07T16-02-54"`